# Laravel helper class not found

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have added

```
app_path().'/classes',
```

to global.php in the ClassLoader::addDirectories array. In app/classes/helpers/Url.php I have:

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class Url {

public static function prep($str)
{
    if ($str == 'http://' OR $str == '')
    {
        return '';
    }

    $url = parse_url($str);

    if ( ! $url OR ! isset($url['scheme']))
    {
        $str = 'http://'.$str;
    }

    return $str;
}
}
```

Then in a view I have:

```
{{HTML::link(Helpers\URL::prep($place->url), $place->url, array('target' => '_blank'))}}
```

This works fine locally, but on my server I'm getting an error for: Class 'Helpers\URL' not found. I tried going through [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970045/laravel-custom-helper-class-not-found), but it didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: did you run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Yes, but since this isn't loaded in composer it didn't do anything. I've even added the classes directory in composer, then dumped, and still getting the same result.

Comment: `Class Url {}` or `Class URL {}`?

Comment: But in composer.json - under "autoload"/"classmap" - did you add "app/classes",?

Comment: expanding on @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, you're defining `Url` and then using `URL` in your code.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro - I tried URL and Url in all instances and still got the same errors.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange - I tried adding this to the class map and still didn't work.

Comment: When you try to load classes using `app_path()` in global.php, `namespace` won't work. if you need `namespace` then you have to use composer.json autoload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I renamed "app/classes/helpers" to "app/helpers", then added the new app/helpers to composer.json and global.php and ran composer dump. Looking through some of the PHP documentation, it seems like PHP sometimes has issues with using "class", "classes", or other reserved type words in directories and namespaces. I'm still not sure why this was working locally, but not on the server though.

Comment: you have case sensitivity issue perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, no. As stated in an above comment. I tried both ways and still was getting the same error, just in different cases.

Comment: my helpers not loading no one server but loading on another server while i add the path into global.php, then i add into composer.json and do dump-autoload they now work.

Answer (score 1):

in config/app.php in the `aliases` array define your Helper facade like so

`'Helper'          => 'Helpers\Url'`

then you can do `Helper::prep()`

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still getting the same error, just more code from the framework was loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I was following https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091089/1454622 (his "Option 1", which I prefer).

I had this same issue where it worked on my local but not on my remote server. **It was directory and file permissions issues on my app/storage**. My remote needed these (thanks @elliotyap ):

1) My helper class is in `app/libs`, so I added to my `composer.json` file in the `autoload` section: `"app/libs",`

2) `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

And it also needed some permissions changes:

3) `sudo chgrp THE_SERVERS_WEB_SERVER_USER_HERE app/storage`